# Sending file and path in FormData with AJAX. Getting Undefined index ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code. What I'm trying to do, is sending a file and a path to put it on the server. I need the path to be from these variables, because I want to output the file later.

```
var FD = new FormData();
 var MyString = "uploads/docs/KEP" +  myVariableString + ".jpg";
  FD.append('name', MyString);
  FD.append('file', $('#file-1').prop('files')[0]);
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cashe: false,
            data: FD,
            url: "ajax/ajax.elszamolfileupload.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            });
```

On the other side, in the PHP:

```
$placeForFile = $_FILES['name']; 
rename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$placeForFile);
```

I'm getting back that "name" is undefined.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: `$('#file-1').prop('files')` what is this?

Comment: `cashe: false,`, you mean `cache`?

Comment: I do mean cache sorry

Comment: `$placeForFile = $_FILES['name'];` should be `$placeForFile = $_POST['name'];` since it's not a file. It's a string.

Comment: @u_mulder The `File` object of a `FileList` object at index `0` from `<input type="file">` element, where `[0]` property is accessed following `$('#file-1').prop('files')`

Comment: Wow, thanks. That was it. Sorry for wasting your time. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $_POST['name'] instead $_FILES['name']

Answer (score 0):

`FormData().append(...)` does not support single `'` quotation marks

the following line

```
...
FD.append('name', MyString);
...
```

you must change it with the one below

```
...
FD.append("name", MyString);
...
```

and use it normally  `$_FILES['name']`